# Openweather API Refusing Connection

Tags: jquery, openweathermap

I'm certain that this is something that I've missed when reading documentation for API's - I'm attempting to hard code a request in jquery to call the openweather API as the page is geographic specific:

```
console.log('Connected to Script.js');
$(document).ready(weatherSettings);
function weatherSettings () {
  var config =
  {
    url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/forecast',
    data: {
      id:'7281804',
      appid: 'MYID'
    }
  };
  $.ajax(config).done(displayMelbourneData);
  function displayMelbourneData(callback) {
    console.log(callback);
  }  
}
```

The error I am getting however is: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your current URL to http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast and you should be fine.

You can try directly try this in your browser **(remember to change YOURAPIKEY with your own API key)**

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=7281804&appid=YOURAPIKEY

Below is a sample that I tried and worked. By the way don't forget to change YOURAPIKEY with your own API key.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>

    console.log('Connected to Script.js');
    $(document).ready(weatherSettings);
    function weatherSettings () {
      var config =
      {
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast',
        data: {
          id:'7281804',
          appid: 'YOURAPIKEY'
        }
      };
      $.ajax(config).done(displayMelbourneData);
      function displayMelbourneData(callback) {
        console.log(callback);
      }  
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```